# Hide property from Swagger conditionally?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a class that I am annotating with Swagger annotations for documentation of our API. One such class is used as part of the Response for two different endpoints. However, we are using `@JsonView` to hide some of the properties of the class for the different endpoints. When our Swagger.json is generated, the hidden properties are shown for both responses.

I was able to hide the properties completely by annotating them with `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)`, however this hid them from both responses. Is there any way to use the JsonView to hide the properties only from some responses?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is NO, there is no current support for conditional behaviour for ApiModelProperty.

Long answer - its quite a challenge - becauae as far as swagger/springfox issues go( [#805](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/807),[#563](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/563) ).
seems there is support of JsonView, and this feature was added to release version `3.0.0`, also seems that issue [#805](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/807), is very similar to what you are facing, so its a good place to start.

It also mentions that there is a way, but it involves removing JsonView and rely on mapping DTOs to Models using [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/)'s `@Mapper` annotated Interfaces, which let you generate different DTO's for the same model.

And from a personal opinion, I think there should a seperation of responsibity here and have a 1:1 relationsip between DTO and request/response models or content, maybe have those specific cases be handled using plain old java way.

From top of my head assuming your usecase is for a Student object:

#### Absraction

```java
public interface Student {
    int getId();
    String getName();
    String getAge();
}
```

#### Model

> also acts as controller, can access the view layer and data layer

```java
public class StudentModel implements Student {
    private int id;
    private String insuranceNumber;
    private String natSecurityNum;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    public double calculateEnrolmentFee() {
        // some database/service calls 
    }
    public StudentInfo getInfo(){
        // map model to info dto
    }
    public StudentDetails getDetails() {
       // map model to details dto
    }
   
    public void terminateEnrollment() {
        // some behaviour and state changes
    }
    // Override Student's getters
    .
    .
    .

}
```

#### View

> For endpoint 1

```java
public class StudentInfo implements Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String age;

   // Override Student's getters and add setters
    .
    .
}
```

> For endpoint 2

```java
public class StudentDetails implements Student {
    private int id;
    private String insuranceNumber;
    private String natSecurityNum;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    // Override Student's getters and add getter/setter based on design
    .
    .
    .
}
```

You can use builders aswell.